# Facebook: Liking content within facebook fan page application

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have an application which will run inside a Facebook Fan Page tab. The only difficulty is, I have pages inside the app that I need to add a like button to.

It's easy to add a normal like button, as the content is obviously hosted on a website. However, when it appears on the users feed, I would like it to appear as a link to the application post page, not the website.

For example the actual URL would be something like:

```
www.example.com/news/article/id
```

And the post regarding the like would link to this page in a new window - displaying the app out of context.

Instead I need it to display as a link to the app, something like:

```
http://www.facebook.com/fanpagename?sk=APP_ID&url=/news/article/id
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If the site is only to be viewed in facebook could you not set the OG url tag to be `http://www.facebook.com/fanpagename?sk=APP_ID&url=/news/article/id` ?

Comment: Good idea but facebook strips everything but the basename (can be demonstrated using the fb debug tool)

Comment: would it be a massive deal if you change to using a feed dialog box? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your page and click the **Edit Page** button.
On the left side, click **Apps**
Now click the link **Link to this Tab** for the tab you are interested in linking to, copy this link.

Finally, go to this link...
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
And using the link copied above generate your like button.

Comment: Thanks but see my comment above, everything but the base domain and page name will be stripped

Comment: Ah, yes. Even if you post the tab's link directly in your feed on Facebook, the link preview will be for the page, not the tab (there will be two links -- one for the page and one for the tab). So I really doubt that what you're trying to do is possible.